# How to square an array of numbers in ruby without `map` or `collect` methods?

Tags: arrays, ruby, math

This is code I currently have

```
def square_array(array)
    array.each do |i|
      i ** 2
    end
end
```

I know it's not correct, could someone explain this process to me please?

Comment: The only problem with your code is that you square each number but then don't do anything with it, whereupon it disappears into the ether. Have you considered storing the squares somewhere?

Comment: you're throwing away the values.  The only difference between `each` and `map` is that `each` just runs the block and does nothing with its return value, while `map` collects the return values into an array. I have no idea why you would want to avoid using `map` for this.

Comment: What possible real-world scenario leads you to need to avoid `map`? It is the best and most correct approach.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses, I am doing this as apart of a class and this is what the exercise called for.

Comment: I remember the excercises in basic and c that called for looping without using FOR.

Answer (score 2):

**Using `each` and `<<` with an empty array**

```
def square_array(array)
  arr = []
  array.each { |i| arr << i ** 2 }
  arr
end

my_arr = [1, 2]
p square_array(my_arr) #=> [1, 4]
```

Here we've created a new empty array `arr`. We then iterate through the other array `array` which is passed as an argument, squaring each element before pushing it (using `<<`) into our new array `arr`.

Finally we return the newly created array `arr` by simply writing `arr` as the final line in the method block. We could have written `return arr` but in Ruby the `return` keyword can be omitted.

---

**Using `each_with_object`**

A slight evolution of the above technique

```
def square_array(array)
  array.each_with_object([]) { |i,arr| arr << i ** 2 }
end

my_arr = [1, 2]
p square_array(my_arr) #=> [1, 4]
```

---

**Using `each` with an Enumerator**

```
def square_array(array)
  Enumerator.new do |y|
    array.each { |e| y << e ** 2 }    
  end
  .take(array.length)
end

my_arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]
p square_array(my_arr) #=> [1, 4, 9, 16]
```

Here we create a new enumerator. We then write instructions for the enumerator telling it (when called upon) to yield values y according to the `each` block.

We then call all the yielded values for the given array by using `take` which returns an array with said values.

Comment: sagarpandya82... thank you. everything checked out...thanks again

Comment: Please don't toss out code. Explain *WHY* the code is useful. It's the difference between giving someone a fish or teaching them how to fish. Help them understand.

Answer (score 1):

You need the index of the array element in order to set it to something else, so we will use `each_with_index`, and set the original array element to the new value:

```
irb(main):001:0> j = [2,3,4]
=> [2, 3, 4]
irb(main):002:0> j.each_with_index { |e, i| j[i] = e**2 }
=> [4, 9, 16]
irb(main):003:0>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use `map`, it seems natural to use `reduce` instead:

```
def square_array(array)
  array.reduce([]) { |a, n| a << n * n }
end
```

But if that violates the spirit of the restriction, you could do it in a more manual way:

```
def square_array(array)
  [].tap do |a|
    array.each do { |n| a << n * n }
  end
end
```

Comment: +1. `#reduce` is the answer here. It is a universal method of iteration, after all, *everything* that can be done with `#each` or `for … in` can be done with `reduce`, including (but not limited to) `map`, `group_by`, `sort`, `any?`, `all?`, `grep`, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way using simple `inject`. For Doc refer: [INJECT](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject)

```
> ar = [2,3,4,5]
=> [2, 3, 4, 5]
> ar.inject([]){|a,b| a << b**2}
=> [4, 9, 16, 25]
```

Answer (score -1):

As has been pointed out in comments, `map` or `collect` is the natural way to do it in Ruby.  However, if you just **have** to do without:

```
def square_array(ary)
  a = Array.new(ary.length)
  ary.each_index { |i| a[i] = ary[i] * ary[i] }
  a
end
```

Comment: Uh, mutating arguments is *big* no-no, unless absolutely necessary and stated very clearly in the documentation. (I don't believe there is a single method in the Ruby core library, the Ruby standard libraries, or any of the widely used third-party libraries that mutates its arguments.)

Comment: `map`/`collect` do not modify anything. They return a *new* `Array`. And even if they *did* modify the `Array`, there's still a *big* difference between modifying the *receiver* (i.e. playing with your own private parts) and modifying an *argument* (i.e. playing with *someone else's* private parts).