# In Ruby, how do you square a numbers in an array?

Tags: arrays, ruby

```
numbers = [1,2,3]

def square_array(numbers)
  numbers.each do |number| 
  "#{number}."
  end
end
```

My code is above, I am just beginning coding. I am getting it to return the original array, but the objective is to return the values in the array squared. I though it would simply be "#{number}**2" but it isn't returning squared values. I can't use .map, .collect, or .inject.

Comment: Why can you not use map or inject?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36141555/how-to-square-an-array-of-numbers-in-ruby-without-map-or-collect-methods/36141754